# jQuery Color Picker on-functions fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all. I've added jQuery colorPicker to my webpage and I'm trying to implement the forth example of it. You can find it on this page.

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about

After my implementation, everything works except for the options added in the colorPicker. I can't change the standard color and onShow, onHide & onChange never fires.

Can anyone see why?

Here's my code:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
 color: '#0000ff',
 onShow: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
  return false;
 },
 onHide: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
  return false;
 },
 onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
  $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
 }
});
```

});

And here's the rest of the code implemented:

```
<div class="settings-color"><div id="colorSelector"></div></div>
```

Added scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
  google.load("swfobject", "2.2");
 

 
  swfobject.embedSWF("signaturetool.swf", "tool", "490", "700", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", null, {allowScriptAccess: "always", align: "middle"}, {id: "signaturetool", name: "signaturetool"});
 

 -->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
```

I've tried with both jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery 1.4.2. I've also tried with removing swfobject for a while and other css options. It all seems to fail, why?

Answer (score 0):

For the onChange method, it tries to apply style rules to `$('#colorSelector div')`, which doesn't exist in your html.

For other methods, I guess they still fires, just you don't feel it.

Comment: #colorSelector div is appended by the javascript files included so the div exists. I've tested it and it doesn't fire at all if I for example place alert('hello world'); inside of any of the on-functions.

Comment: But the script doens't append the div inside of the #colorSelector div either. Major problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

The right settings was in the layout.js-file and that's why it didn't respond on the index.php-file. When I applied my functions in the layout.js everything worked.